# Integration of Payment Gateway with angularjs application with spring backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, payment-gateway

can anyone suggest me the flow of Payment Gateway integration in Angularjs Application with spring at Backend.

what is the best approach to do it?

my dilemma is that from back end we only fetch data in JSON and have very less control on views/redirection. I don't want to call payment gateway from javascript because of obvious reasons.

what will be the flow in such case. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have built entire Payment Gateway + EFT Switch using the combination of JPOS(ISO8583 message router), Spring JPA (database management), SparkJava(REST JSON data API) angularjs(frontend application) and Apache qupid for messaging.

In your case you could create dynamically create an iframe to load external payment gateway in your angularjs partial page/view.

```
var payload = 'https://yourexternatpaymentgateway.com?reference='+$scope.payment.reference+     '&name='+encodeURIComponent($scope.payment.name)+'&custid='+$scope.payment.phone+'&amount='+$scope.payment.amount+'&source_page=http://yourfeedbackpage'+
'&description='+encodeURIComponent($scope.payment.description);

jQuery('#console').html('<iframe width="100%" height="550px" src="'+payload+'" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>');
```